# recursive algorithm string match

Tags: python, string, recursion

I recive 2 strings. I have to implement a recursive function that return the best option for them to be similar by adding -. I give an exemple cause this is not good description

```
str1="sdfsdf"
str2="dffd"
```

the  best option will be

```
str1="sdfsdf-"
str2="-df--fd"
```

how do I implement this is recursion?? I dont know how to start thinking on it.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance might be a good start

Comment: You can't add - to sdfsdf to get sdfdf-, you also have to remove an s. Can you clarify exactly what you mean?

Comment: This isn't an easy task, just saying.

Comment: oh I made mistake. 
    str1=sdfsdf-
    str2=-df--fd

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this is a variant of the classic Longest Common Subsequence problem. You can solve this basic dynamic programming by first finding the LCS, and then adding '-' to unify the two given string. Recursive algorithm follows a top-down approach but often leads to low efficiency, while the non-recursive version could solve the basic LCS problem bottom up and helps you understand the core part of dynamic programming.

```
def lcs(a, b):
    m, n = len(a), len(b)
    stable = [[[0,'-'] for j in xrange(n+1)] for i in xrange(m+1)]
    for i in xrange(1, m+1):
        for j in xrange(1, n+1):
            lu, l, u = stable[i-1][j-1][0], stable[i][j-1][0], stable[i-1][j][0]
            stable[i][j][0] = (lu + 1) if a[i-1] == b[j-1] else max(l,u)
            if a[i-1] == b[j-1]:
                stable[i][j][1] = '`'
            elif l > u:
                stable[i][j][1] ='<'
            else:
                stable[i][j][1] ='^'

    i, j = m, n
    similara, similarb = list(a), list(b)
    while i > 0 and j > 0:
        if stable[i][j][1] == '`':
            lcstring = a[i-1] + lcstring
            i -= 1
            j -= 1
        elif stable[i][j][1] == '<':
            similara.insert(i, '-')
            j -= 1
        elif stable[i][j][1] == '^':
            similarb.insert(j, '-')
            i -= 1
    while len(similara) < len(similarb):
        similara.insert(0,'-')
    while len(similarb) < len(similara):
        similarb.insert(0,'-')
    return stable[len(a)][len(b)][0], lcstring,''.join(similara), ''.join(similarb)
```

you can get the length of LCS, the LCS itself, the 2 converted strings by the above function

```
>>>print lcs('sdfsdf', 'dffd')
3, 'dfd', sd-fsdf, -dff-d-
```

Answer (score 0):

It is exactilly the sequence comparision question in biology. The only difference is in DNA we only have A T C G and -, anyway the algo is the same. google it and you will find a lot of answers. It is one of the fundamental questions in Bioinfomatics and has been thoroughly studyed.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using, for example, dynamic programming (although there are more efficient algorithms, some of which are described in the article on the [Longest Common Subsequence Problem on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem)).

Here's a simple but inefficient recursive solution. Note that in the worst case it runs in time exponential to the size of the input strings.

```
def match(a, b, prefa='', prefb='', cost=0):
    if not a:
        return cost + len(b), prefa + '-' * len(b), prefb + b
    if not b:
        return cost + len(a), prefa + a, prefb + '-' * len(a)
    if a[0] == b[0]:
        return match(a[1:], b[1:], prefa + a[0], prefb + b[0], cost)
    return min([match(a[1:], b, prefa + a[0], prefb + '-', cost+1),
                match(a, b[1:], prefa + '-', prefb + b[0], cost+1)])
```

It outputs the cost (the number of '-'), as well as the diffed strings.

```
>>> print match('sdfsdf', 'dffd')
(4, 'sdf-sdf', '-dff-d-')
```